# In NiFi how to get redis key of HGET

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

I am using HGET command to get the value of redis below is the command I am using:

```
HGET "1234" "rules"
```

So, by using the above the command I am getting the rules key values. SO, How can I get the same result in NiFi, which processor I need to use. I have used FetchDistributedMapCache processor but it is giving exception.

Comment: That is the correct processor, please show the error you are getting, preferably with the stacktrace from nifi-app.log

Comment: How can i use hget,  I mean where to specify those keys

Comment: There is currently no way to use specific Redis commands, you can go through the distributed cache interface which uses GET and PUT behind the scenes

Answer (score 0):

It is not a great solution, but I used ExecuteStreamCommand for this.  It is very slow, but the only solution I could come up with.

For instance, to perform an HGET, have the ExecuteStreamCommand invoke a bash script, like this:

```
HASHNAME=$1
FIELD=$2
RET_VALUE=`redis-cli HGET $HASHNAME $FIELD`

echo $RET_VALUE
```

Set the processor to return to an Attribute.